# In Eclipse eGit I need to review all changes before pulling into my local

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

FYI: I've recently transitioned from subversion so all I have to reference is what I did there.

We have team members that often times commit bad code to the repo. I have no way to prevent this, and I'm not looking for a way. But what I used to do in subversion is when updating my local copy I could easily see ***all*** repo changes in the sync view. And I could do the code review right there, merge their changes line by line, and make changes to my local copy, essentially forcing a conflict+merge to correct their bad code. And do it all from a single view, only having to worry about the two versions in front of me - local vs remote, and seeing all files at once.

I can't figure out how to do this in eGit. The sync view only shows my commits to the repository, not incoming updates. And doing a pull does not give me the ability to interactively modify incoming the *non-conflicting* files, which is extremely important because most of their updates are not merge conflicts. So now I have to pull the updates, and then figure out which files they modified one a time, and go from there.

How can I accomplish the same update/merge flow I used in SVN?

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use Eclipse, but it shouldn't interfere with Eclipse either. Maybe those  commands can be somehow done via the Eclipse UI, I'm not aware how limited it is though.

Open a terminal with `git` and `cd` into your project's directory.

First run `git fetch` to download all the changes made by your teammates. Note that this is a rather "safe" command - it doesn't touch your working directory and can't lead to any conflicts. It simply "updates" the internal local copy of the remote repository you fetch from so it's aware of all changes made since you last fetched. (`git pull` is simply a `fetch` followed by `merge` automatically).

After fetching, you can see all new (and old) commits and their respective changes in the [commit graph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Inspecting_the_Commit_Graph).

If you want some to apply some of the changes of some commit to your working directory, write down the hash of that commit and then run `git checkout -p <hash>`.

This will start an interactive prompt that will allow you to pick which changes from that commit you want to apply to your  working directory and which changes you don't want to apply to your working directory.

If the changes are not fine-grained enough you can use `s` to further split the current chunk into smaller chunks.

I know you didn't ask for this but in case someone else comes across this - this is an extremely awkward way to work and is rather uncommon. Usually your teammates should write unwanted changes in separate feature-branches that only merge to the main branch when they're ready. Everyone derives from the main branch and it should be golden with only positive changes. Having to constantly pick and choose all changes made by others sounds tedious and will only get worse when more people add to the repository. See [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) for a simpler way to work, if you ever look for one.

Comment: The nice thing about EGit is that you don't have to learn Git command line commands (Git command line does not even need to be installed). This makes it much easier for beginners, because they can concentrate on the Git concepts instead of learning all the commands and arguments. You should have a look at EGit first, before you recommend alternatives for it.

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback, this doesn't do a good job of replacing the SVN team sync view because it involves constantly hopping around, copy/pasting hashes, etc, which is not acceptable from a time point of view.

As for feature branches, they present the exact same problem. Before merging them I need to see a concise, easy to use sync screen. And the process we work under will not allow them to sit in a feature branch while I do a code review. They will be forced to merge by people that are out of my control.

Comment: @TheShoeShiner In Git, there's also a _Synchronize_, but it's a complete different thing than in SVN and you don't usually use that at all. The concepts and way of working in Git and in SVN are completely different. Unfortunately, it takes time to learn Git and knowing SVN does not help here.

Comment: @howgler I did not suggest an alternative to egit, this is merely an additional way to achieve the specific task he's looking to perform, in addition to using egit. It doesn't replace it any way, it's just not done through it. I really doubt there's a wrapper around `git checkout -p` (or something similar) in EGit. I know about the advantages (and disadvantages) of git GUI's, I don't see how they're relevant here.

Comment: @Omer Your answer and comment is based on the wrong assumption that EGit is a GUI for git-core. The question is how to do it in Eclipse and not on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In Git, the way of working is quite different than in SVN.

In SVN, you first merged the latest state from the server into your local/working copy. On the merge you acted as gatekeeper by reverting or improving the changes of the others. After that you have committed your version to the server, where it has been put as a new revision on top of the history stack.

In contrast, in Git you think of changes, not of states. A commit is a change that can be applied to multiple branches ([cherry picking](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cherry_Picking)). That works even if the files to be changed are different. In SVN there is already a merge conflict when the same file is affected, but in Git you will only get a conflict when the same line or nearby lines are affected. This means that in Git you very rarely have to manually resolve conflicts compared to SVN. And the good thing is that it also means that changes can be also reverted at a later point in time.

In Git, do the [rebase](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Rebasing) (or [merge](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Merging)) task and your gatekeeper task as two separate tasks. First do a *Pull*, so that when there are changes from others that have been pushed to the remote server in the meantime, your change will be moved to the end of the history. Only in rare cases (when your change/commit affects lines that have been changed by others in the meantime) you have to manually resolve these conflicts in the *Git Staging* view. But in most cases you just do a *Pull* and you are ready to commit and push your change in the *Git Staging* view. Independent of the change you made, you can review the changes made by others in the *History* view, and if needed revert or improve them later. To revert a commit, right-click and choose *Revert Commit* which creates a new commit with the inverse change. If you want edit this revert commit (for a partial revert), right-click the previous commit and choose *Reset > Soft or Mixed*.

Comment: Edit: I take back the initial comment, history is not file-by-file, so I can indeed select the root and see all commits, but it doesn't show me the comparison from my current state to the HEAD, because my current state has already been updated.

Comment: If you want to see the total change of multiple commits (because a lager change was made in several consecutive commits), in the _History_ view select the two commits, right-click and choose _Compare with Each Other_. What you should definitely not do is to mix your changes with corrections of the changes of the others like you did in SVN. Because if you mix these into one commit, you lose the possibility of independently undoing changes with a simple revert commit and the possibility of applying individual changes to another branch. Get rid of the SVN thinking of states, think in changes.

Comment: I guess that's the fundamental problem. I don't want to overwrite my local state (which is what a pull would do) until I know for certain that I've reviewed and corrected the code. So I want to be able to see what's incoming (or what just came in) all at one time, and at the same time compare it to *what was there*. I can't figure out how to do this in eGit. "Compare with each other" only shows me single files. I need to see it for the entire state of the remote repo vs mine.

Comment: In SVN a commit is a set of new/deleted/edited files, in Git a commit only contains a diff of changed (new/deleted/edited) lines, not the whole file. You can' t apply your SVN thinking to Git: the changes you see in your workspace from other after a _Pull_ will not be part of your commit, since a commit is only the delta. If you want to undo/revert one or more commits, you have to commit the inverse delta. If you mix your commits with the reverting of other commits, you lose the power of Git and it will result in a lot of unnecessary manual merging. Just review in a different local branch.

Comment: I don't mind reviewing in another branch, but the problem is I can't see what it is I need to review because there is no concise compare screen that compares files. The commits coming in are messy and reviewing them independently has no value. A lot of this may go back to the initial statements about the quality of the work, and the way the team uses it, etc, but those are things I can't change.

Comment: Yes, in Git you use a separate local branch for each separate thing. So, in the review branch you have all changes of the others checked out and you will compare them back with your last good commit before these changes. You compare backwards, not forwards like what you are used to in SVN, and the changes are already applied. This has the advantage that you can run, navigate, etc. the code and you do not have to judge only by looking at the incoming changes. Sure, this is different from what you are used to in SVN, but it is much easier.

Comment: @howgler Except I can't run the code. Often times it's broken by the new commits and contains both compile issues and runtime issues. So I guess I'd need two different eclipse projects? One for my "good" code and the other for the latest remote version. Then I need some way to sync between them. I want to make this transition, but honestly for what I need to do, this does not seem easier. But I'll admit I could still be missing something around merges.

Comment: And I still can't understand how I can efficiently review individual commits. If I review them in chronological order then I could very well be reviewing / testing something that the developer completely removed 10 minutes later. This is why I need to compare against the latest state of the repo.

Comment: 1. Fetch, 2. Check-out remote master/main branch as local branch, 3. Right-click project and choose _Compare With > Commit..._ and choose the commit before the commits to review, 4. If required, _Commit and Push_ the review changes